# Sprite Kit Animation timed to various sound files - GOAL: animation auto ends at end of each sound file to avoid manually timing each one

Tags: ios, animation, audio, sprite-kit, skaction

**Hello! First question ever asked here!**

I have a SpriteKit project with a variety of characters and sounds.

The characters are animated to a whole mess of varying sounds based on the scenes.

I am trying to find a way that the animations will end when the sound file completes playing. Currently I am using the following setup which would involve manually calculating the count for each scenario.

```
func animateCharacter() {
       
        let soundAction = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("sound", waitForCompletion: false)
        let animateAction = SKAction.repeat(SKAction.animate(with: animatedFrames, timePerFrame: 0.1, resize: false, restore: true), count: 3)
        
        character.run(SKAction.sequence([soundAction,animateAction]))
        
        }
```

Is there any way to automate this so that each animation repeats for the length of each sound file?

I've tried using repeatForever along with removeAllActions - but that didn't seem to work?

I'm pretty green here but I'm guessing a type of completion handler based on audio file length?

Please help.

Thanks!

Brought to you by Carl's Jr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right to use repeatForever and removeAllActions, a few amendments are needed though.

Amend your *animateAction*, you want to use the repeatForever rather than counting manually, so change this:

```
let animateAction = SKAction.repeat(SKAction.animate(with: animatedFrames, timePerFrame: 0.1, resize: false, restore: true), count: 3)
```

To this:

```
let animateAction = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: animatedFrames, timePerFrame: 0.1, resize: false, restore: true))
```

You can run your animate action at this point also, so add this on the row below it:

```
character.run(animateAction)
```

Your *soundAction* needs to have *waitForCompletion* set to **true**, as per the docs: ***If true, the duration of this action is the same as the length of the audio playback. If false, the action is considered to have completed immediately.*** You will notice that both your sound and animation run at the same time, even though you put *SKAction.sequence*.

Your sound action should look like this:

```
let soundAction = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("sound", waitForCompletion: true)
```

Because your wait for completion is now true, we can run the audio then remove actions once the audio has completed like this:

```
  character.run(soundAction) { [self] in
    character.removeAllActions()
  }
```

**SUMMARY**

This is the final code:

```
  let animateAction = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: animatedFrames, timePerFrame: 0.1, resize: false, restore: true))
  character.run(animateAction)
  
  let soundAction = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("sound", waitForCompletion: true)
  character.run(soundAction) { [self] in
      character.removeAllActions()
  }
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. Glad I was on the right path! I will need to add some sort of time modifier to be able to fine tune the end points - any suggestion as to where to look for that?  Thanks again.

Comment: Could you expand on the fine tune end point thing, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Sure! The length of the audio files includes a little bit of "dead air" ( like 0.25 or 0.5 seconds)  at the end so the animations don't end when the actual sound ends - It would nice to be able to end the animations at (length of file) - (0.5 seconds) or something like that. I've done it with timer stuff a little bit - like now() - 2.0 or something along those lines. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok. I understand what you are saying, the issue you'll have is each sound file has different dead air, so you'll have to manually cater for each file somehow. I think you are better off downloading a free audio editor (e.g. Audacity) and trim the end of each sound file.

Comment: Yeah I may just do that - I have 50+ sounds that would need modding - that's why I was hoping to do it programmatically - even though it would still be tedious but less so than editing the actual files. Thanks for your help!